# Kinetic energy of a gas molecule

Tags: energy, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

I am working through the derivation of the equation 
$$pV=\frac13mNC_{rms}^2,$$
but relating to this formula my textbook states that the kinetic energy of an average molecule of gas is given by 
$$KE=\frac12mC_{rms}^2$$
but how is this formula right since the mean squared speed ($C_{rms}^2$) is not the same as the average speed of the molecule squared, $v^2$, so why do we use the mean squared speed for kinetic energy and not the means speed squared? Is it just that it is easier to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we use the mean squared speed for kinetic energy and not the means speed squared? Is it just that it is easier to calculate?

The expectation value of kinetic energy is
$$\langle T\rangle=\left\langle\frac{1}{2}mv^2\right\rangle=\frac{1}{2}m\langle v^2\rangle=\frac{1}{2}mC_\text{rms}^2$$
where $C_\text{rms}=\sqrt{\langle v^2\rangle}$.

It is important to note that in general, $\langle v^2\rangle\neq\langle v\rangle^2$, so using the mean speed squared is actually incorrect.